# what is (1<<OCIE0A) in C?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, avr

I know that `OCIE0A=0001` in binary, so would `(1<<OCIE0A)` just be 0010? I see this being used quite frequently, what is the reason for setting a register to `(1<<OCIE0A)` and not just setting it to 0010 directly?

Comment: What is `OCIE0A`? A name of a variable?

Comment: There's no `I` in hex. Furthermore, it wouldn't even be close to `0001`.

Comment: please tell me why this was down voted

Comment: According to [this link](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~rod/Winter2007/4723/notes/timer0/timer0.html), "Output Compare Match A Interrupt Enable" for a 8-bit timer in an AVR microcontroller. And it's a RW flag, so I don't know why you think it should always equal to 1.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your question right now isn't very clear since we don't know what `OCIE0A` is.

Comment: @Mysticial then i guess i misinterpreted this. I too don't know what this is. But it pops up in avr mcus. I would think that its some kind of variable

Comment: Mentioning AVR MCUs in the original question would have helped a lot. You can't expect people to know that type of context.

Comment: @mugetsu: it doesn't have to be 1 always. Provide some context code so that it would be easier to explain why it's used that way.

Comment: `OCIE0A` is an identifier (it starts with a capital `O`, not a digit `0`).  A question asking about it should explain what it is; most of us have no idea beyond what we might find in a quick Google search.

Comment: @Mysticial: There's no `I` in hex, but there is one in HEXADECIMAL!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Judging from the results of a Google search, it appears* to be the name for the bit that controls "Timer/Counter Output Compare Match A Interrupt"* in the "Timer/Counter Interrupt Mask Register"* of a "8 bit AVR Microcontroller"* Its usage is as follows*:

```
TIMSK0 |= _BV(OCIE0A);  // enable compare A interrupts 
TIMSK0 &= ~_BV(OCIE0A); // disable compare A interrupts
```

Where `TIMSK0` is* the Timer Interrupt Mask Register*.  `OCIE0A` is an identifier that (to someone familiar with AVR code*) is more immediately understandable* than `TIMSK0 |= 2`*.

They using bit identifiers instead of masks since any halfwit compiler can optimize them to the same thing for bit->mask, but going from mask->bit is harder*.  So by leaving it as the bitid, it's easy and fast for all usages*.

On an unrelated note, numbers are values stored as binary in the computer.  "Decimal" and "Hex" are *representations* of those values.  So no, OCIE0A is not "hex".  It is a symbol that represents the bit offset of a flag, with the value of 1.

<sub>*assumptions everywhere, I know nothing</sub>

Comment: As an embedded programmer, I totally agree. I hate reading old code and finding 'config_reg=0x051C' .   "Oh crud, I have to go find the reference manual again".    It's much better to see 'config_reg=EN_FIFO | EN_INT | WORD_SZ_8;'

Comment: You are completely right with your assumptions. Also look here for more on that topic: http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html#faq_use_bv

Comment: An excellent answer considering it appears it wasn't clear it was an AVR register bit. A good reason to keep the symbolic name is that you may need to translate when moving a program to another chip. A reason they use bit numbers rather than masks is that the same definitions work for assembly, where there are some single bit operations (SBI, SBIC, SBIS, SBRS, SBRC, CBI, BSET, BST, BLD...) that take a position.